# Steam StorefrontAPI returns 403 when called on server by proxy

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I'm getting a 403 errors when fetching data by proxy from StorefrontAPI - [docs](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI#appdetails). This seems to be an authentication error, but I can't find any auth method for this API. This error occurs only when using a remote server, but on localhost all is fine, and the same sent by Postmen returns excepted data.

My proxy server is using node.js, express and http-proxy-middleware.
This is an example query: `https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=323190` (the parameter is the game id).

I have both my backend (proxy) and frontend hosted on render.com.
[Here is the app adres](https://games-updates-monitor.onrender.com/)

[And for the backend](https://games-updates-monitor-backend.onrender.com/)

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/lkucharzyk/games-news-monitor/tree/d0426eb191e671b9f482b0f1e809888631c09817)

(Sorry for that mess in commits, I just tried some random things to fix that problem.)
I expect my app correctly fetching data from the API.

Comment: Hi, you linked your whole repo. You are expected to create a minimal, reproducible example, to increase the chances to get an answer. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you